# APPWIDGET_UPDATE Oreo compatibility

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

In the app manifest I'm subscribed to this broadcast receiver

```
       <receiver
            android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/widget_label_big">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
                <action android:name="com.mydomain.action.UPDATE_WIDGET"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
        </receiver>
```

APPWIDGET_UPDATE is not in the android Implicit Broadcast white list https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Is this compliant with android O?
If no, what solution can I adopt to be notified to APPWIDGET_UPDATE?

Comment: when you send a broadcast, you need to make sure the intent is explicit in order to work on O.

Comment: It may not be in the list of exceptions, but it's still the official way used in the documentation. Looks like you have to test whether this still works yourself. Make sure to report whether it did.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble receiving your broadcasts, in Oreo and up, when creating an `intent` for the `sendBroadcast`, you must specify the class that must handle it or it will not fire.

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.mydomain.action.UPDATE_WIDGET");
i.setClass(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

These actions are not in whitelist but it's not deprecated and widgets works fine on api 26+. In addition android dev team add some new api for working with widgets (interacting with user like pinning etc.)